# Plugin system for statically linked modules in C?

Tags: c, plugins, static-libraries, static-linking

I need to write a plugin system which works with statically linked modules on Linux.
I do not want the core (main function) to explicitly call the init function for the module.

The closest analogy which I can think of, for what I want to accomplish, is the Linux kernel.
There it is possible to have a unknown number of modules/plugins compiled and linked statically, but the modules are initiated as would be if they were loaded dynamically.

I have this

#### core/main.c:

```
 int main(void) { return 0; }
```

#### core/pluginregistrar.h:

```
#ifndef PLUGIN_REGISTRAR_H
#define PLUGIN_REGISTRAR_H

#include <stdio.h>

#define module_init(pInitor) \
    static inline funInitor __inittest(void) \
        { fprintf(stdout, "test\n"); return pInitor; }
    int init_module(void) __attribute__((alias(#pInitor)));

typedef void (*funInitor)(void);

#endif
```

#### adap1/main.c:

```
#include "pluginregistrar.h"

void adap1Init(void) { fprintf(stdout, "test1\n"); }

module_init(adap1Init);
```

#### adap2/main.c:

```
#include "pluginregistrar.h"

void adap2Init(void) { fprintf(stdout, "test2\n"); }

module_init(adap2Init);
```

so far, but I have no idea on how to get the core to actually initiate the modules which have done a module_init.

Can anyone here give me a pointer? (no pun intended)

EDIT:
I changed core/main.c to

```
extern int init_module(void);
int main(void) {
  init_module();
  return 0;
}
```

and it not shows the call of the "adaptation" which was first in the library list given to the linker.

Comment: i don't think linux kernel modules are linked statically then loaded dynamically. unless i am mistaken, kernel modules are dynamically linked.

Comment: Am I missing something? What can't be done with just a bunch of function pointers and a few structs? Possibly with some `__attribute__((constructor))`

Comment: @AdrienPlisson You might be right, but I don't think so. If you were then the bzImage would have to be a compressed archive - which it as far as I know - is not. It is however compressed.

Comment: @awoodland Not sure that I follow you.

Comment: The other, more portable option would be [libltdl](http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/html_node/Libltdl-interface.html), which can make staticly linked "modules" look like they're dynamically linked.

Comment: @fredrik: well, i am not sure i understand your question. do you want to build a module which can be linked statically or dynamically depending on the way an application is build ?

Comment: @awoodland The target system has no MMU, hence all libraries which handle dynamic modules are not available, unfortunantly.

Comment: @AdrienPlisson As I said in the previous comment, the target has no MMU, so dynamic linking is out of the question. What I want is static linking and modules/plugins.

Comment: @fredrik - libltdl works with statically linked things too. It creates the illusion to the programmer that it's dynamically linked always, but works equally well with static things. I guess I should write it up as an answer, but that might not be for a while.

Comment: @awoodland Then it might work. But after reading the 11.1 section you linked to I cannot find a method of finding available symbols, only to locate symbols of which I know the name (which might not be the case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GCC, you can use the `__attribute__((constructor))` specifier to have one piece of code run at startup (before `main`) for each of your "modules". (Also works with clang and ICC.)

For example:

```
$ cat t.c
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef AAA
static void  __attribute__((constructor)) myinit()
{
    printf("%s\n", AAA);
}
#else
int main()
{
    printf("bye\n");
    return 0;
}
#endif
$ gcc -DAAA=\"hello\" -o  m.o -c t.c 
$ gcc -DAAA=\"there\" -o  n.o -c t.c 
$ gcc -o t.o -c t.c
$ gcc -o foo m.o n.o t.o
$ ./foo
there
hello
bye
```

(Code provided for illustration purposes only.)

Once you have that, you're pretty much good to go. Have that "constructor" function do whatever the module needs to do to initialize itself, and "register" into your plugin framework. (A structure with a bunch of function pointers, added to a linked list or something like that would work.)

Note that link order will determine your plugin initialization order, and that's a can of worms - if your modules depend on each other, things get really tricky. Make sure you have as few globals as possible.

#### Update:

If you need to use static libraries rather than plain `.o` files, you need a bit of extra linker magic.

Assuming the above has already run:

```
$ ar cru libm.a m.o
$ ar cru libn.a n.o
$ gcc -o foo t.c -Wl,-whole-archive libn.a libm.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive
$ ./foo
hello
there
bye
```

I'm not entirely certain of whether you can rely on (reverse) link order in this case.

Or:

```
$ ar cru libmn.a m.o n.o
$ gcc -o foo t.c -Wl,-whole-archive libmn.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive
$ ./foo 
there
hello
bye
```

(And here I have no idea of what contructor order you'll get.)

Comment: This is exactly what I was suggesting in my comment. Then you can have `extern int init_module(void);` changed to be a function pointer, which the `__attribute__((constructor))` function in your module gets to set to point to its implementation. (Or an array of function pointers if more than one module can be active)

Comment: This seems to be really close to what I need, but here each t.c is compiled as object files, not static libraries.

Comment: @awoodland Ohh, I didn't follow you at all then. An array of function pointers it would have to be, problem with an array is that it have to be indexed and that means a global index which I don't know when anyone controls.

Comment: @Mat Perfect, now I just have to integrate this in a good enough manner in my make system. Thanks!

Comment: @fredrik: glad I could help. Just a friendly word of advice: take a _lot_ of care with initialization and memory management in those "constructors" and the functions they call. Bugs before entering main can be _really_ difficult to track down and squash. So keep it as simple and lightweight as possible, and defer anything too complex to "normal" code inside/after main. Have fun :-)

Comment: @Mat Thanks for the warning and heads up.

Comment: `libm.a` is not a very good name for your own library, by-the-by ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is only one entry point in a program, and by default that is `main`.  What you are suggesting, if I understand it correctly, is to have multiple entry points.  As far as I know, that is not possible in standard C.

If you are statically loading the libraries (meaning that they are passed into the linker, regardless of whether they get included in the resulting executable), then you will have to export their initializers in header files, and explicitly call `module_init` on each one of them.

If you are dynamically loading the libraries (using a mechanism like `dlopen`/`dlsym` from [dlfcn.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dlfcn.h.html)), then you may call `module_init` on demand once you have determined what modules to load and when to load them.

In either case, you *must call* `module_init` if you want it to be run.  You can refactor to hide it, but at some point it must be called.